# C# Adding button with value at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to add a button with value to my tab control during runtime. A lot of tutorial show how it's done while creating connecting with database. Is there any way that it can be done without connecting to database?

[image]

After I input data into both textbox and clicked save, new button should appear on tab control on another form.

Comment: Show us your code. Adding a button to something on its own has absolutely nothing to do with connecting to a database, so yes, it is possible to do that.

Comment: A key part of this question is what framework you are using: Are you trying to add a button to a web page? To a Windows application (WPF)?

Comment: @JamieF i'm using window forms application

Comment: @Glubus I have edited my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you save button put :

```
 private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                x = 4;
                 y = panel1 .Controls.Count * 70;
                Button newButton = new Button ();
                newButton.Height = 150;
                newButton.Width = 60;
                newButton.Location = new Point(x, y);
                newButton.Text= "your text";
                 newButton.Click += new       
              System.EventHandler(Button_Click);             
              tabControl1.TabPages [0].Controls.Add(newButton);

        }
```

And also you can handel the click of new button created :

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender ;
        MessageBox.Show("Button is pressed "+button .Text );

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, your code are working to display new button on tab control but the save button don't get the data from the textbox.

Comment: You can change newButton.Text= "your text";  to   newButton.Text= textbox1.text";

Comment: If the answer was helpful for you please mark it ,thanks

Comment: Yes, it helped. Now I'm trying to adjust the position on the tab control when new button is appeared.

Comment: Ok thanks ,i have edit my answer to show you how change position ,good luck

Comment: @Thank you! It's working great now.

Answer (score 0):

I propose such decision

Main form:

```
namespace stackoverflow
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private static Form2 new_form = new Form2();

        public MainForm()
        {    
            InitializeComponent();
            new_form.Show();
        }


        void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new_form.CreateBtn( richTextBox1.Text );
        }
    }
}
```

Second form:

```
namespace stackoverflow
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private Button btn = null;

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void CreateBtn( string text ) {
            if ( btn == null ) {
                btn= new Button();
                btn.Parent = this.tabPage1;
            }
            btn.Text = text;
            this.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Buttons
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const int ROWS = 5;
        const int COLS = 10;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        }
        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new MyButton(ROWS, COLS, this);
        }


    }
    public class MyButton : Button
    {
        const int WIDTH = 50;
        const int HEIGHT = 50;
        const int SPACE = 5;
        const int BORDER = 20;

        public static List<List<MyButton>> buttons { get; set; }
        public static List<MyButton> buttonList { get; set; }
        public Form1 form1;
        public int row { get; set; }
        public int col { get; set; }
        public MyButton()
        {
        }
        public MyButton(int rows, int cols, Form1 form1)
        {
            buttons = new List<List<MyButton>>();
            buttonList = new List<MyButton>();

            this.form1 = form1;
            for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
            {
                List<MyButton> newRow = new List<MyButton>();
                buttons.Add(newRow);
                for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
                {
                    MyButton newButton = new MyButton();
                    newButton.Height = HEIGHT;
                    newButton.Width = WIDTH;
                    newButton.Top = row * (HEIGHT + SPACE) + BORDER;
                    newButton.Left = col * (WIDTH + SPACE) + BORDER;
                    newButton.row = row;
                    newButton.col = col;
                    newRow.Add(newButton);
                    buttonList.Add(newButton);
                    newButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(Button_Click);
                    form1.Controls.Add(newButton);
                }
            }
        }
        public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyButton button = sender as MyButton;
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Pressed Button Row {0} Column {1}", button.row, button.col));

        }

    }
}
```

---

Make dynamic

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication72
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const int ROWS = 5;
        const int COLS = 10;
  
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            new PictureText(10, this);

 
        }
    }
    public class PictureText : Panel
    {
        const int WIDTH = 50;
        const int HEIGHT = 50;
        const int SPACE = 5;
        const int BORDER = 20;

        public TextBox textbox { get; set; }
        public PictureBox picturebox { get; set; }
        public int row = 0;
        public static List<PictureText> pictureText = null;

        public PictureText() { }
        public PictureText(int rows, Form1 form1) 
        {
            this.Left = BORDER;
            this.Top = BORDER ;
            this.Width = 2 * (Width + BORDER);
            this.Height = rows * (HEIGHT + BORDER);
            this.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            form1.Controls.Add(this);
            pictureText = new List<PictureText>();

            for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
            {
                PictureText newRow = new PictureText();
                this.Controls.Add(newRow);
                pictureText.Add(newRow);

                newRow.textbox =  new TextBox();
                newRow.textbox.Text = "Hello";
                newRow.picturebox = new PictureBox();
                newRow.picturebox.BackColor = Color.Green;
                newRow.picturebox.Text = "Goodbye";
                this.Controls.Add(newRow.textbox);
                this.Controls.Add(newRow.picturebox);


                newRow.textbox.BringToFront();
                newRow.textbox.Height = HEIGHT;
                newRow.textbox.Width = WIDTH;
                newRow.textbox.Top = row * (HEIGHT + SPACE) + BORDER;
                newRow.textbox.Left = BORDER;


                newRow.picturebox.BringToFront();
                newRow.picturebox.Height = HEIGHT;
                newRow.picturebox.Width = WIDTH;
                newRow.picturebox.Top = row * (HEIGHT + SPACE) + BORDER;
                newRow.picturebox.Left = 2 * (BORDER + Width);
            }
        }
    }
 
}
```

Comment: How does this answer OP's question? You're using columns and stuff, OP doesnt. Onclick you show a messagebox, OP does not want this behavior. Clearly OP could use this code to dick around in his own project, but you could at least elaborate on your code snippet.