# Trying to set certain labels to certain part of a multidimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm currently trying to display a multidimensional array onto a table panel with labels(like an excel sheet), to show the contents I have to assign an array segment to a specific label, but as seen below, it's very tedious. Is there any way I could make this easier? I know I can use a for loop or foreach loop, but don't know how to go about doing it.

First post, don't hesitate to point out anything wrong with the post, Thank you :)

```
    int x;
    int y;
    string output;
    string[,] boxes = new string[6,6];

        boxes[x, y] = output;
        //groupx
        Box1.Text = boxes[0, 0];
        Box2.Text = boxes[1, 0];
        Box3.Text = boxes[2, 0];
        Box4.Text = boxes[3, 0];
        Box5.Text = boxes[4, 0];
        Box6.Text = boxes[5, 0];
        //groupx
        Box7.Text = boxes[0, 1];
        Box8.Text = boxes[1, 1];
        Box9.Text = boxes[2, 1];
        Box10.Text = boxes[3, 1];
        Box11.Text = boxes[4, 1];
        Box12.Text = boxes[5, 1];
        //groupx
        Box13.Text = boxes[0, 2];
        Box14.Text = boxes[1, 2];
        Box15.Text = boxes[2, 2];
        Box16.Text = boxes[3, 2];
        Box17.Text = boxes[4, 2];
        Box18.Text = boxes[5, 2];
        //groupx
        Box19.Text = boxes[0, 3];
        Box20.Text = boxes[1, 3];
        Box21.Text = boxes[2, 3];
        Box22.Text = boxes[3, 3];
        Box23.Text = boxes[4, 3];
        Box24.Text = boxes[5, 3];
        //groupx
        Box25.Text = boxes[0, 4];
        Box26.Text = boxes[1, 4];
        Box27.Text = boxes[2, 4];
        Box28.Text = boxes[3, 4];
        Box29.Text = boxes[4, 4];
        Box30.Text = boxes[5, 4];
        //groupx
        Box31.Text = boxes[0, 5];
        Box32.Text = boxes[1, 5];
        Box33.Text = boxes[2, 5];
        Box34.Text = boxes[3, 5];
        Box35.Text = boxes[4, 5];
        Box36.Text = boxes[5, 5[;
```

Comment: The main trouble with adding Elements to the GUI in a loop is getting the Positions right. For that reason most people use one (and often one nested) for loop rather then foreach. That way you can use the Runnign variable(s) as part of the math. If you got any container that can take the layout load from you, use it.

Comment: You might want to look at generating your textboxes via code and storing them in an array as well, which would allow you to easily map your values array to your textboxes.

Comment: Thing is, I'm doing this for a high school programming class, but we mainly only use the GUI for adding elements, but if it makes it easier to code, I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: See my example at following posting for adding buttons.  Buttons and TextBoxes are both controls and can be added dynamically using the same methods.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165402/c-sharp-adding-button-with-value-at-runtime?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa