# Changing picturebox #N

Tags: c#

I want to set up a `for` loop to change the content of pictureboxes with using like `picturebox[i]` but I can't figure out how to do that.
My idea was doing something like this, the whole code snippet has a lot of if statements but is similar to this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    pictureBox[i].image = Image.FromFile("../Pics/Salmon.jpg");
}
```

I don't know how to do it and I cant' find anyone with the same problem. Is there any way how to do this? Or do I have to manually do it.

Comment: is `pictureBox` a single picture box? or is it supposed to be a collection like an array or list?

Comment: With #N i meant number N, like in the forloop. The picturebox is just a simple picturebox in the GUI. The way i add pictures to the picturebox right now is with this 


                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("../Pics/Salmon.jpg");

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: The code i posted was just an example of what i thought it'd look like, using it like that doesnt work.

Comment: See my response on following postings.  It show how to add dynamic buttons.  You can replace Buttons with your picture boxes : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165402/c-sharp-adding-button-with-value-at-runtime

Comment: since I don't know how your picture boxes are arranged on your GUI I would suggest to collect them in a collection like `List<PictureBox> myPictureBoxes`. This one you can then use like in your for loop example

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the PictureBox controls in an array. They are part of the overall control collection on a form. You can loop through all the controls on a form and only act on the picture boxes.

Example:

```
 foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
 {
     if (ctrl is PictureBox picBox)  //determine if the control is a picture box
     {             
         picBox.Image = Image.FromFile("../Pics/Salmon.jpg");
     }
 }
```

Or using Linq:

```
this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToList()
    .ForEach(p => p.Image = Image.FromFile("../Pics/Salmon.jpg"));
```

Or if you have to act on based on posistion array:

```
var pics = this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < pics.Length; i++)
{
    pics[i].Image = Image.FromFile("../Pics/Salmon.jpg");
}
```

Comment: this is a good approach as long as all PictureBoxes are on the plain GUI. If one of them is inside a panel, or group box or some other control, then you won't reach it

Comment: Agreed @MongZhu, that would require recursion to check all child controls.

Comment: var pics = this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < pics.Length; i++)
            {
                if (storage[i].Contains("Salmon"))
                {
                    pics[i].Image = Image.FromFile("../Pics/Salmon.jpg");
                }
                else if (storage[i].Contains("Tacos"))
                {
                    pics[i].Image = Image.FromFile("../Pics/Tacos.jpg");
                }





Did i do this correcly?
https://gyazo.com/e301fc28d968072136b7debe4471de4c
This is What my gui looks like, sry idk how to format.

Comment: @adde09 - not knowing your complete solution that may work. You should consider a more robust solution so that you don't have to write all of the if statements. I would consider creating a user control for each combination of recipe and image. In the long run it would be a much more maintainable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare collection first and then iterate it:

```
var pictureBox = new[] { pictureBox1, pictureBox2, ... };
for (int i = 0; i < pictureBox.Length; i++)
    pictureBox[i].Image = Image.FromFile("../Pics/Salmon.jpg");
```

You can use same approach to have different pictures, I'll let it for you as a kind of exercise ;)

Comment: This ended up being my solution, just didnt think about using arrays before this lol, such an obvious solution. thanks.