# C# How to Build dynamic panels within run time

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am retrieving data from MySql database , I want to Build these panels with their contents dynamically in run time according to number of food I have.
How I will Do that[Demo For Food List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yi2Bh.png)

Comment: You should create one main panel and the add one sub panel to main panel for each food list.  then add a picture box to each of the sub panels.  Adding panels (for each food type) is the same as adding a button dynamically.  See my solution at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165402/c-sharp-adding-button-with-value-at-runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Suggest you to make a UserControl with all your layout for one item. (PictureBox, label etc).

Then for each item in you DB you create a new instance of your UserControl class with needed informations. After that, you just have to place each control in you form (or use an auto layout).