# How to use this.Controls dynamically tools as a matrix?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to make a matrix with some Controls and modifies them within the matrix?

We can take a look at a minesweeper game for example. If all the buttons are dynamically created, we insert them in this.Controls (just for this case). Bombs are randomly placed on some buttons and I need to place numbers on the others equal to the number of bombs around them.

So, using just a List, this thing is hard to be achieved. It would be easier with a matrix, taking directions on X and Y (8 directions) and find the bombs. Is there a way to simplify this problem?

I don't know if some code will help, but I will show what I've made so far.

```cs
        private bool[] bombs = new bool[400];
        private int counter = 1;
        private int bombsFound = 0;
        private Point p = new Point(0, 0);
        private void GenerateMineSweeper()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 15; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= 25; ++j)
                {
                    Button box = new Button();
                    box.Location = p;
                    box.Size = new Size(25, 25);
                    box.BackColor = Color.RoyalBlue;
                    box.Padding = new Padding(0);
                    box.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup;
                    box.Click += new EventHandler(box_Click);
                    this.Controls.Add(box);
                    bombs[counter++] = false;
                    p.X += 23;
                }
                p.Y += 23;
                p.X = 0;
            }
            counter = 0;
        }

        private void GenerateBombsLocations()
        {
            // For 15*25 = 375 boxes will be set 75 bombs

            Random rand = new Random();
            int j;
            for (int i = 1; i <= 75; i++)
            {
                j = rand.Next(1, 375);
                while (bombs[j] == true)
                {
                    j = rand.Next(1, 375);
                }
                bombs[j] = true; // Add bomb
                counter = i;
            }
            lbl_bombsTotal.Text = counter.ToString();
            counter = 0;
        }

        protected void box_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = sender as Button;
            var indexOfThisButton = this.Controls.IndexOf(btn);
            if (bombs[indexOfThisButton] == true)
            {
                btn.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
                btn.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + @"\bomb.jpg");
                bombsFound++;
                lbl_bmbFound.Text = bombsFound.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                btn.Enabled = false;
                btn.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                int i = BombsAround(indexOfThisButton); // find how many bombs are around
                btn.Text = i.ToString();
            }
        }

        private int BombsAround(int index)
        {
            int bombs = 0;

            // find bombs

            return bombs;
        }
```

[picture with the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enaRu.png)

Comment: First thing I think of is `tablelayoutpanel`. You can add rows and columns dynamically and create controls for each cell.

Comment: I have done it a lot in the past.  Sometimes I have both a single array of buttons and two dimensional array of buttons and add same button to both.  See following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165402/c-sharp-adding-button-with-value-at-runtime

Comment: Also, check my repo on [GitHub](https://github.com/ertanyildiz/ping). it can give you the idea of using `tablelayoutpanel`

Comment: Code create a custom class that inherits the standard button but adds a row and column property so when the button is clicked I can use one Event handler which know the row and column of the button pressed.

Comment: @Badiparmagi I think using a tableLayoutPanel is not the case as it will look bad because of the spaces between cells (even if I use DockStyle.Fill). If you know how to make it looks like the photo above, would be nice.

Comment: Deriving your own class from a Winforms control is an entirely normal and expected programming technique.  Easiest way to add HasBomb, X and Y properties to a button.  And nothing wrong with aggressively separating the data from the view, if you want a "matrix" then simply declare a two-dimensional array to store the data.  A bool is not enough, so create a little helper class that has at least a HasBomb and Button properties.  Mapping the clicked button back to the array indices is a bit ugly but plenty fast enough for a human.  Or just use both techniques.

Comment: @HansPassant what if I have multiple buttons on the form? how to i know which one will be set as a game button. Supposing there are 2 more buttons, one for "exit" and one more for "Logout", placed with drag and drop on the form, are they going to have a X and Y prop as well?