# flowlayoutpanel wont show all items with c#

Tags: c#, flowlayoutpanel

I got a flowlayoutpanel in my program so that whenever I click on the category button, it will show the corresponding items in the FLP. However, the scrollbar showed up but it wouldn't let me scroll to the bottom to see all the items.

here is my code to add the 'sub items'

```
public void createItemBtn(List<String> itemList, Control panel, EventHandler handler)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < itemList.Count; i++)
            {
                Button newButton = new Button();
                newButton.Width = 203;
                newButton.Height = 132;
                newButton.AutoSize = false;
                newButton.Name = "newBtn" + i;
                newButton.Text = itemList[i].ToString();
                btnList.Add(newButton);
                panel.Controls.Add(newButton);
            }
            //add event handler to ecah button 
            foreach (Button btn in btnList)
            {
                btn.Click += new EventHandler(handler);
            }
        }
```

and here is the picture of how it looks like when it comes out 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSCm1.jpg

Comment: I do not like using flowlayoutpanel because it does not always work.  The flowlayoutpanel does not implement all the properties of a panel. I prefer to create my own by adding to a main Panel child panels.  doing my way will allow you to add a scrollbar to the main panel and separate scrollbars to the children.

Comment: With layout problems so many things can be wrong in the background. Add a screenshot of the document Outline and the Properties window of the Panel itself.

Comment: @jdweng it was easy to keep the button in order and such, thats why I use it

Comment: I would suggest using TableLayoutPanel in that case since the buttons are kept perfectly ordered

Comment: Easy doesn't mean it will work.  Just reduces the number of lines of code.  It is more important to have working code.  See my solution at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165402/c-sharp-adding-button-with-value-at-runtime

Comment: Imo FLPs work just fine. I can't repoduce your issue. You did turn on AutoScroll, right?

Comment: The horizontal scrollbar should not be there.  Wrapping the loop with Suspend/ResumeLayout() might fix it.  If not then make the panel a bit bigger/buttons a bit less wide.

Comment: @TaW I did turn on the AutoScroll, scroll bar is always there, but it seems like it never detect if there are items outside of the screen and require more scrolling

Comment: @HansPassant I just tried it with the suspend and resumelayout, but nothing happened. I can reduce the size of the button and that might fix the issue by not needing the scrollbar, but user might add new items into it later on, and that might excess the limit again

Comment: wrt the hScrollbar: You need to make the flp wide enough to accomodate as many panels as you want __including__ their `Margin` __plus__ the scrollbar width. - As I said I can't reproduce the vScrollbar issue here.

Comment: @TaW thanks for the reply, i just tried to change the AutoScrollMinSize, which allows me to scroll down more now, but the button that I created wasn't fully draw on the panel, its cut off like the way it is from the image, and the buttons after that are all missing. so i guess theres also something wrong with drawing the buttons?