# Adding multiple Pictureboxes or labels with text and images

Tags: c#

I want to have multiple cards with text and images or just red or blue color filled up. [this is how the form should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLaYk.jpg). So I am thinking about creating multiple picture boxes or labels But the problem is that the picture boxes are overlapping.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Createlabels();

    }
private void Createlabels()
    {
        var n = 5; 
        PictureBox[] p = new PictureBox[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            p[i] = new PictureBox();
            p[i].Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\sania\Desktop\c sharp project\red1.Png");

            p[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            p[i].Left = i * 100;
            this.Controls.Add(p[i]);
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Createlabels2();
    }
    private void Createlabels2()
    {
        var n = 10; 
        PictureBox[] q = new PictureBox[n];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)

        {
            q[j] = new PictureBox();
            q[j].Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\sania\Desktop\c sharp project\blue.Png");
            q[j].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            q[j].Left = j * 100;
            this.Controls.Add(q[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First I would create a main panel and put picture boxes in the panel.  Adding Picture boxes dynamically is the same as adding buttons dynamically.  See my solution at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165402/c-sharp-adding-button-with-value-at-runtime/37165767

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more please its not clear for me how to do it

Comment: You have to be more specific what is not clear.  The button example I posted is a very good example.

Comment: I actually couldn't understand how to use the panel. Like for example, I am using two different types of buttons instead of using picture boxes as I can not enter the text to picturebox. What I want is showing 2 different types of cards like as I already mentioned in the picture before.But problem is its overlapping each other like for the first button creates 10 boxes and the next one creates 10 as well and it's on top of each other

Comment: I usually create : public class MyButton : Button and add properties so you have one type button.  Or you can create a mini panel that has a picture box and a label.  Then add the 20 mini panels to the main panel.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I did so far [my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9xfO.jpg)  but it [should look like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5J5I.jpg)

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var n = 12;
        Button[] p = new Button[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            p[i] = new Button();
           p[i].Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\sania\Desktop\c sharp project\red1.Png");



            p[i].Text = i + " Reserved";

           p[i].Left = i * 100;
            this.Controls.Add(p[i])
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Createlabels2();
    }
    private void Createlabels2()
    {
        var n = 12;
        Button[] q = new Button[n];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            q[j] = new Button();
            q[j].Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\sania\Desktop\c sharp project\blue.Png");


            //"ImagePanel" is a TableLayoutPanel
            q[j].Text = j + 10 + " Booked";
            q[j].Top = j * 100;
            this.Controls.Add(q[j]);
        }

    }

}
```