# SQL, UserControla and FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, sql

When I click on the button, how can I create as many usercontrols as the number of data in SQL and add it to the properties in a usercontrol SQL one by one?

Comment: Adding any control to a user form at runtime is basically the same.  See my answer at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165402/c-sharp-adding-button-with-value-at-runtime

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please add more details about your approach?