# is there any way to duplicate section tag with Panel base on record from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to C# and ASP.NET, I'm using Visual Studio 2017. I created a webshop with a SQL database and Entity Framework. I have a Panel in my form inside -section- tag that retrieve all products from the database into the panel. I want to duplicate this -section- tag include the panel for each product type. I already created the method to get the product by type. I want to have -section- with product for each product model in my form.

This is my code

HTML

```
<section class="product-carousel">
        <!-- Heading Starts -->
            <h2 class="product-head">Latest Products</h2>
        <!-- Heading Ends -->
        <!-- Products Row Starts -->
            <div class="row">
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlProducts1" runat="server" 
                    CssClass="IndexPanelProduct"></asp:Panel>
            </div>
        <!-- Products Row Ends -->
        </section>
        <!-- Latest Products Ends -->
```

Code Behind

```
private void FillPage(int type)
{
    ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel();
    List<Product> products = productModel.GetProductByType(type);

    if (products != null)
    {
        foreach (Product product in products)
        {
            Panel productPanel1 = new Panel();
            ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton();
            Label lblShortDesc = new Label();
            Label lblbuysCount = new Label();
            Label lblNewPrice = new Label();
            Label lblOldPrice = new Label();

            imageButton.ImageUrl = "~/Images/product-images/" + product.Image;
            imageButton.CssClass = "productImage";
            imageButton.PostBackUrl = "~/Product_page.aspx?id=" + product.Id;

            lblShortDesc.Text = product.Name;
            lblShortDesc.CssClass = "mainProductDesc";

            lblbuysCount.Text = "Buys 120 +";
            lblbuysCount.CssClass = "mainProductBuys";

            lblNewPrice.Text = "Only for: $ " + product.NewPrice;
            lblNewPrice.CssClass = "mainProductprice";

            productPanel1.Controls.Add(imageButton);
            productPanel1.Controls.Add(lblShortDesc);
            productPanel1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "<br />" });
            productPanel1.Controls.Add(lblNewPrice);
            productPanel1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "<br />" });
            productPanel1.Controls.Add(lblNewPrice);
            productPanel1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "<br />" });
            productPanel1.Controls.Add(lblbuysCount);

            pnlProducts1.Controls.Add(productPanel1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        pnlProducts1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "No Product Found !" });
    }
}
```

Comment: You are adding panels dynamically at run time which is the same as adding buttons at run time.  You are adding the panel on top of each other so you are only seeing the last panel.  The panels left and top properties have to change for each panel.  See my example of adding buttons for solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165402/c-sharp-adding-button-with-value-at-runtime

Comment: i mean if you take a look at Aliexpress home page for example you will see that its divided to category sections like: "Best match" "Flash Deals" etc' and eatch of this category have products base on its category type, i want to know how to create the same category section in my home page

Comment: Do one step at a time.  I was trying to get the panels not to overlap.  Each category will be in a different panel an until you get the panels not to overlap you cannot tell what data is in each panel.

Comment: Im sorry but i dont understend... any way you can show me some example in my code?

Comment: You are dynamically adding panels with : pnlProducts1.Controls.Add(productPanel1);  You are not setting the productPanel1 properties left and top so all the panels you are adding are at the same location.   You need to set the left and top similar to the link I provided.

Comment: where can i add the product category title name ?

Comment: You have a main panel and a bunch of child panels.  So you can add a label to the child panels like the main panel using productPanel1.Controls.Add(textbox).  You just have to make sure you set the location of the text box so it doesn't overlap the panel.  So if you main panel has a height of 100 and width of 100.  You add to sub panels with height of 30 and width of 80 in vertical direction.  The 0,0 (x,y location) of panel is the upper left corner with positive y going down and positive x is towards the right.

Comment: You put the two textboxes and to child panels with width 80 and top location as follows 1) Textbox 1 : from y 5 to 15 2) Child Panel 1 : 20 to 50 3) Textbox 2 : 55 to 65: 4) Child Panel 2 : 70 to 100

Comment: maybe i didnt explain myself clearly, can you please take a look at this website home page, you will see its divided to sections, eatch section shows deferent type of product including header name, my needs is to create page exactlly like it, this is the website: https://www.groo.co.il/

Comment: i need to do it in ASP.NET webform not in C# winform

Comment: It looks like each row is a panel and the panel has children panels which are stacked horizontal.

Comment: yes, do you have any idea how to create it ?

Comment: You need to create for each row a panel and then add to panel children controls which are text boxes and panels.  Then set the Top, Left, Width, Height of the children which are set relative to the parent panel Top/Left  corner (0,0).  Top positive direction is down and Left positive direction is to the right.

Comment: following may help : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/display_data_items_and_details