# Dynamically creating buttons based on a series of XML nodes

Tags: xml, vb.net, winforms

I've been trying to figure out how to dynamically create buttons inside of a flow layout panel. I have an XML document, which contains a growing list of nodes which are adjusted over time. The program grabs each node, and should create multiple buttons for each node (menuItems), but for some reason it only generates one. Here is what I have so far:

```
    Private Sub FORM_Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim pictureButton As New Button 
        Dim m_xmld As XmlDocument
        Dim m_nodelist As XmlNodeList
        Dim m_node As XmlNode

        m_xmld = New XmlDocument
        m_xmld.Load("Menu.xml")
        m_nodelist = m_xmld.GetElementsByTagName("menuItems")

        For Each m_node In m_nodelist

            strID = m_node.Item("ID").InnerText
            strName = m_node.Item("Name").InnerText

            pictureButton.Name = strID
            pictureButton.Width = 150
            pictureButton.Height = 150
            pictureButton.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom
            pictureButton.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("image.jpg")

            FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(pictureButton)

        Next
    End Sub
```

Note the main form, FORM_Main, has a flow layout panel, FlowLayoutPanel.

I initially thought that perhaps it was not generating new buttons as they had the same name, so I have set the name to one of the nodes in the XML file.

The XML file is structured as follows:

```
  <menuItems>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>Item 1</Name>
  </menuItems>
  <menuItems>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Name>Item 2</Name>
  </menuItems>
</DATA_Menu>
```

I am a novice at visual basic so if there is something glaringly obvious I have missed, I would be eager to know what it is!

Comment: Of course it only creates one. Read your own code. How many lines of code have you got that create a `Button`? How many times is that line of code executed? If you want to create multiple `Buttons` then you actually have to create multiple `Buttons`. If you have one friend and you add them to the guest list for a party multiple times, how many people will you have coming to your party? Does adding that one person to the list multiple times magically make them multiple people? If not, why would adding one `Button` to a form multiple times magically make it multiple `Buttons`?

Comment: Does the `For loop` not create a new button with a different ID for each consecutive XML node?

Comment: Why do you need to ask that. Again, look at the code. Where is the line of code that creates a new `Button`? The hint is that it's the only line with the words "New" and "Button" in it. Is that line of code inside the loop?

Comment: Oh, I see. `Dim pictureButton As New Button` must also be in the loop. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: See my answer at following.  The code uses a regular button which can be replaced with any control : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165402/c-sharp-adding-button-with-value-at-runtime  Code is c# but the button adds method are basically the same.