# Unity OnClick.AddListener Stopped Working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, debugging, button, onclick

I am building a card matching game. On start, the game generates 16 buttons (the cards) and each button is given a listener to respond when clicked. Now, up until yesterday this was working perfectly.

Today I tried to add a particle emitter to the scene (made no changed to the code). When I ran the scene to test the emitter, the buttons wouldn't work. I removed the emitter but the problem persisted. I checked the buttons in the inspector and no onClick event has been added to any of them.

No matter what I do I can't seem to get it to add the onClick to the buttons anymore.

Here is my code:

```
      void Start()
        {
            GetButtons();
            AddListeners();
            AddGamePuzzles(); 
            ShuffleSprites(gamePuzzles);
    
            gameGuesses = gamePuzzles.Count / 2;
        }
    
        void GetButtons()
        {
            GameObject[] BtnObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("PuzzleButton");
    
            for(int i = 0; i < BtnObjects.Length; i++)
            {
                btns.Add(BtnObjects[i].GetComponent<Button>());
                btns[i].image.sprite = bgImage; 
            }
        }
    
        void AddListeners()
        {
            foreach (Button btn in btns)
            {
                btn.onClick.AddListener(() => PickAPuzzle());
            }
        }
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I've been pulling my hair out for hours now.

Comment: Yo uneed to register the buttons with '+='.  See my answser at followingposting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165402/c-sharp-adding-button-with-value-at-runtime

Comment: Does the console show any errors? Did you put some logs to see whats really happening? Does your code pass through AddListeners(), is AddListeners getting the correct values for the btns? etc

Answer (score 3):

Firstly I would like to say thank you to those who took the time to try assist me with answers.

The problem turned out to be my own stupidity. I accidentally disabled the Graphic Raycaster on my Canvas, making it impossible to click the buttons. Re-enabling the Raycaster fixed the issue immediately.

Something I learnt out of all this: When you add a listener to a button while the game is running, that listener will not be displayed in the inspector, but it is there.

Comment: Thank you so much for your question and answer! I did exactly the same thing removed the 'Graphic Raycaster' and I've been trying to work out why my buttons weren't working. I've re-added it to my canvas and 'pow!' all my buttons work again. Thanks again